# Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Tags: spring-boot, cxf, jax-ws

I am upgrading the application to Springboot 3.1.2. I am using cxf 4.0.2 dependencies. Also having jakarta xml and com.sun jaxws-rt 4.0.1 dependencies. I am getting the below error

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
```

I hope, I have added all the dependencies but still cant resolve it.

I could see the package `com.sun.xml.ws.spi`, but cant find the package `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi`

Could you please help me to resolve it?